# Angularjs component event for after all children are initialized

Tags: angularjs, lifecycle, angular-components

Looking at the documentation of angularjs [component api events](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) I'm not finding a hook that would fire after all child directives are initialized and linked.

Is there such an event?

I would like to create a component that uses `ngRepeat` to stamp out a bunch of stuff in a template and then use `$transclude` function to transclude content into each one. To understand this, [consider this toy plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/r1zZARIhUGdrVx503QxW?p=preview). You'll note that what we're trying to do is tranclude content into each `li` but of course they do not yet exist on `$postLink`.

Comment: This *feels like* an XY Question.  It's not really clear (even with your plunkr) what you are **really** trying to accomplish with `$transclude` that couldn't be accomplished by structuring the model.  `$transclude` is one of the most misunderstood and misused pieces of angular, and it's really rare that it's even necessary.

Comment: @Claies I guess I'm not sure what is really unclear about this. I suppose in the overall, I'm trying to make a reusable component that works similarly to `ngRepeat` but the component places some additional structures around each of the elements that are transcluded out. I've looked at the source for ngRepeat and it handles a lot of complex situations, so rather than re-implement all of that, I'd rather just compose that into an element that wraps it.

Comment: but that's just the thing, what is "additional structures around each of the elements"?  and if it works "similarly to `ng-repeat`", then why not just use `ng-repeat` instead of re inventing the wheel?  A real world scenario that demonstrates what it is you are really expecting as an output would go a long way, since when I look at your plunkers (from this question and the previous one you asked about `$transclude`) they both look like they are doing exactly what `$transclude` is meant to do.

Comment: in this example, you have a single `<test>` element, and it clones the inner content, loops the content 3 times, and then **replaces** the original inner content with the looped content.  is that not what you were expecting?

Comment: @Claies because thats what a "reusable component" is. Let's say there's a commonly used ui in my app that creates a frame with some standard headers, then a ul, and lis each of which have a standard header and footer. However the *contents* of each item are different depending on usage. I don't want everyone throughout my application to have to copy-paste that templating code every time, I want the reusable component itself to control it so it can be changed at a single point.

Comment: Because an actual component won't duplicate its contents multiple times, each time providing a different scope for them to bind to. In order to do that you *have* to use `$transclude`

Comment: In this example what I expect is for the content of the `<test>` component to be rendered 3 times - once in each of the `<li>` elements with the scope passed to each transclusion being different

Comment: that's not how `$transclude` works.  it's not going to duplicate `<test>` it is going to still only render `<test>` a single time, with the inner html of it replaced.

Comment: @Claies dealt with that yesterday :) Thats actually not true if you use the second `cloneLinkingFn` parameter which seems to be made exactly for my use case. If you want to jump to chat I can explain to you the real world scenario I'm dealing with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152912/discussion-between-george-mauer-and-claies).